# Regarding overlapping text on arrows

Tags: tikz-cd

Surprisingly I failed to find any questions addressing this exact problem. I have used 'shift right/left' to obtain the desired spacing between the arrows, however I still need to force the text on one of the arrows to appear on the opposite side. Is there a simple command for this?

[image]

Comment: Use the option `swap` on the left arrow, it will typeset the label on the opposite side.

Comment: Works great, cheers!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the option `swap` on the left arrow, it will typeset the label on the opposite side.

A quick example:

[image]

```
\documentclass[margin=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzcd}
        A   \arrow[d,xshift=-1mm,swap,"left"] 
            \arrow[d,xshift=1mm,"right"] \\
        B
\end{tikzcd}
\end{document}
```

Comment: You can use `shift right` and `shift left`; the side is with respect to the arrow direction.

Comment: @egreg I'm not sure I understand your comment, sorry.

Comment: Instead of `xshift=-1mm` you can use `shift right=1mm` (or just `shift right` that's good for a first attempt).

Comment: @egreg That wouldn't yield the same result, though.

Answer (score 0):

every label is set to the left side of the arrow by default. So you could always turn around your direction of arrow with `<-`. Could be helpful if you do this a lot and do not want to alternate the shifting directions. Just to give one more solution to such a basic question. Alenanno's way is the typical one for sure...

```
% arara: pdflatex

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}

\begin{document}
\[
\begin{tikzcd}
\cdots \arrow{r}{d_{i+2}} & M_{i+1} \arrow[shift left=1.2]{d}{f_{i+1}} \arrow{r}{d_{i+1}} & M_i \\
\cdots \arrow{r}{e_{i+2}} & N_{i+1} \arrow[shift left=1.2,<-]{u}{g_{i+1}} \arrow{r}{e_{i+1}} & N_i
\end{tikzcd}
\]
\end{document}
```